# What is the $block->getData(), $block->setData() method in Magento 2? How to use them?

Tags: blocks, magento-2.0

I'm a Magento beginner. My question:

What is the `$block->getData()` and `$block->setData()` methods in **Magento 2**? How to use them? 
And could you show me the list of all Magento's methods (`getData(), setData()`...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**getData()  and setData()** are [php getter setter magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

**`$block->setData('variablename',$Value)`** means you have set value `($variablename)`for  variable **variablename**  for your current  for   **current block class**.

In order to getd assiged value for **variablename** value ,you can use `$block->getData('variablename')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you give a specific example for it, please? I don't know how to use it. :D

Comment: @MinhTamPham setting a argument (id, class etc.) for a block in an XML file and then using that value in the block class